# sed find replace (inplace replace) using regex

Tags: sed

I need to find and replace certain text in many files. I am trying to use sed to do the replacement. Here is what I am trying to do:

Find:

```
<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>([^<]*)</b></font>
```

replace with:

```
<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>$1</title></b></font>
```

Esentially I want to add a `<title></title>` tag around what ever I find.

e.g. if the text is like:

```
<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>THIS IS MY TITLE</b></font>
```

I want to replace it with:

```
<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>THIS IS MY TITLE</title></b></font>
```

I have tried various commands, but it does not seems to work. Here aare the commands that I have tried so far:

```
sed -e 's/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>\([^<]*\)<\/b><\/font>/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>\1<\/title><\/b><\/font>/g'
sed -r 's/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>([^<]*)<\/b><\/font>/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>\1<\/title><\/b><\/font>/g' 
sed -E 's/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>([^<]*)<\/b><\/font>/<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>\1<\/title><\/b><\/font>/g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this works

```
sed  '/font *size *= *"4" *face/s|<b>\([^<]*\)</b>|<b><title>\1</title></b>|g'
```

my idea is to avoid as much escapes as possible and break matching and substitution in two steps

Comment: this will change all `<font size=..><b></b></font>` not only for those `"face" attributes` :)

Comment: True, Kent! Thanks for the comment. I corrected the post. In any case, you can just extend the match as to make sure that you just edit the lines that are relevant for you

Comment: that's why I just did "copy & paste". since I could not "make sure". but you are right, man can always test and then change a little and test again. :)

Comment: I need to find the exact string, because there are some other similar strings in the page which I don't want to replace.

Comment: That should not be a problem. My idea was to split the problem in two parts: matching and substitution. First you make sure you just match those lines you are looking for: /font size=..../. Add as much detail as necessary. And then perform your substitution s|...|...|g. In sed /condition/s,this,that,g means: for those lines matching condition, substitute all ocurrences of this with that. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work. However, I don't think I can update the files with this. Can you tell how I can make these replacements in all files and save them?

Comment: this way you create new files, containing the changes and with extensions ".fixed": for f in <file pattern of results of find command>; do sed '...' $f > "$f.fixed"; done

Comment: If you use something like ${f%%\.html}_fixed.html, then you add a suffix to the file name. The options are countless...

Answer (score 0):

a sed line was basically built from copy & paste ^_^.  please try it:

```
kent$ (master|✔) echo '<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>THIS IS MY TITLE</b></font>'|sed -r 's@(<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b>)([^<]*)(</b></font>)@\1<title>\2</title>\3@'
<font size="4" face="verdana, arial,geneva"><b><title>THIS IS MY TITLE</title></b></font>
```